# What is missing (while loop)?

Tags: python, while-loop, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to sum a number like: n -> n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1. My code is working, but not doing what I wanted it to do. I would like to know if I'm missing a parameter or something like this.

```
def s(n):
    a = n-1
    r = 0
    while a != 1:
        r = r + a
        a = a - 1
    return r
print (s(10))
```

Comment: How can it be both working and not doing what you wanted it to do?  What do you want the result of `s(10)` to be, and what is your code printing?

Comment: @Samwise: Reading between the lines working means it throws no exceptions and not-working means it doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: Can you clarify with some sample input, expected results, and what this thing is returning instead? Like what do you expect `s(10)` to spit out?

Comment: If `n` is 1 do you expect the answer to be 2 or 1?

Comment: it looks like based on your description you are starting at the wrong index. Did you try setting `a=n` then decrementing from there?

Comment: A simpler solution might be `return sum(range(1, n+1))`.

Comment: My naive assumption is that you want `10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1` or `55`. If that's the case then change `a = n - 1` to `a = n` (otherwise you never add `10` to your total) and change `while a != 1` to `while >= 1:` (otherwise you never add `1` to your total) and rerun.

Comment: Make sure you only ever call this function with values greater than 1. Easier would be *return int(n/2*(n+1))*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to debug code is to try walking through its execution with a simple example.

Let's try 4. We would expect to get the answer 4+3+2+1 = 10.

- `s(4)`
- Before the loop starts, `a=3`, `r=0`.
- After the first iteration,
  `a=2`, `r=3`.
- After the second iteration, `a=1`, `r=5`.
- `a != 1` is now `False`, so the loop ends, and we return `r`, which is `5`. We only ever added 3 and 2 to it, and forgot to add 4 and 1.

Looking at this a level higher, your function is always missing the first (`n`) and the last (`1`) values of the sum. Fix both of these mistakes and your function should work how you expect. These are both examples of the classic [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error) - your fence is missing posts at both ends.